# How to release a locked file

Tags: files

We have a file server running ubuntu server. Sometime, when one of the users is using a file and closing it, the server still shows that the file is locked for editing.

How can I release that lock? Is there a fix for this problem?

The ubuntu server is 10.xx.

Comment: What file type is it? A document? A picture? Which program is used to open the file?

Comment: And what protocol do you use to access the files? Samba/SMB/CIFS or NFS, or ...

Comment: Just a general hint: Ubuntu 10.04 is not longer supported - so it could make sense to consider upgrading this machine in the near future. I am aware that this is not a solution - but you should keep it in mind.

Comment: This might be related with hidden `.~lock` files which still exist

Comment: @dufte How would the EOL state of the release cause lock files to be made for files?

Comment: @thomas it doesn't

Comment: @dufte It's unclear then in your comments that's what your intention was going for.  Which is why I asked :)

Comment: @ThomasWard - i mentioned it - as running unsupported versions is afaik often commented as 'not supported by community either'. To split this from my main pointer regarding .lock files i used 2 comments in a row ;)

Answer (score 2):

To unlock a folder using your terminal, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens,  navigate to the locked folder, or file, and run the command(s) below:

```
sudo chown -R username:enter_username folder_name
```

Or

```
sudo chown -R username:enter_username file_name.ext
```

Comment: dont know if the api changed but I needed to omit "username:" what I used was "sudo chown -R username folder_name"